# how to retrieve a value from "Purchase Line"."Shortcut Dimension 2 Code" in Ms. Dynamic NAV?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, dynamics-nav

I just create a Global Variable in Ms. Dynamic Nav 2009 R2 and I set its datatype to RECORD and select a specific table(Purchase Line). After that I add a Textbox to Classic Report and set its SourceExpr : "Purchase Line"."Shortcut Dimension 2 Code". Then I go to RTC report and Add that field to RTC report. After run RTC report. I get a blank value. Did you ever experiece in this scenario?Please help me. I just want to retrieve a value from "Purchase Line"."Shortcut Dimension 2 Code".

Thank in advance

Makara

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tested whether the field works in the classic client report?

Additionally you need to remember that when you use a global variable in this manner (as opposed to a report data item), that you need to manually get the relevant record from the database in your C/AL code in the OnAfterGetRecord trigger for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Where about is the field located on the RTC Report?
It must be within the main body, and cannot be within the header or footer sections on the RTC, otherwise the value wont appear without additional code.

Comment: Yeah, I did that on Body of RTC. Still no value showed, But in the table there are some values...

Comment: It sounds like the record isn't populated. Can you see the values in the classic client?

Comment: Of course , It did showed some values in Classic, But it didn't RTC

Comment: And you have the DataSetFieldName set on the field in the Classic client? If you were able to select it in the RTC it should be, but just being thorough.

Otherwise, check the visibility/hidden conditions on the cells, rows and table to ensure it's not being filtered on the RTC report.